# $\{p_{n}\}$ is a sequence of real numbers. Prove $\limsup$ $\{p_{n}\} < \infty$ if and only if $\{p_{n}\}$ is bounded above.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

I have done the following.

$\Leftarrow$

$\limsup$ $\{p_{n}\}$ is the set of suprema of all the subsequential limit points of 
 $\{p_{n}\}$. So, if it were not finite, then, given any $M\in N$, there would have to exist subsequence $\{p_{n_{i}}\}$ having limit larger than $M$. So $M$ could not an upper bound of $\{p_{n}\}$.

$\implies$

If  $\{p_{n}\}$ is bounded above, then it has a supremum in $R$ say $\alpha$. So $\alpha\geq p_{k}$ for all $p_{k}\in \{p_{n}\}$. This implies, $\alpha\geq p_{k_{i}}$. Thus, $\alpha$ is an upper bound for all subsequential limit points of $\{p_{n}\}$. Since $\limsup$ is the supremum of all subsequential limits, it follows that $\limsup$ $\{p_{n}\} < \infty.$

Is the proof correct and rigorous enough? I think in both the implications I have assumed $\{p_{n}\}$ is bounded above. Is this correct?

Comment: I think it's fine.

Comment: By bounded I suppose you mean bounded above.

Comment: Yes bounded above

Comment: @Henno Brandsma: I think in both the implications I have assumed $\{p_{n}\}$ is bounded above. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is fine.

For a quicker one, use the definition
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} u_n = \inf_{N\ge 0} \sup_{n > N} u_n
$$